# do nothing on close application javafx

Tags: java, javafx, application-close

how can I make sure that the window does not close when I click on the X?

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest((WindowEvent t) -> {
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Attention");
    alert.setContentText("Would you close the application?");
    ButtonType buttonTypeOne = new ButtonType("Yes");
    ButtonType buttonTypeTwo = new ButtonType("No");
    alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonTypeOne, buttonTypeTwo);
    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

    if (result.get() == buttonTypeOne) {
        stage.close();
    } else if (result.get() == buttonTypeOne) {
        // NOT CLOSE
    }
});
```

Comment: This has been asked elsewhere - I’ll search when I am back at the computer - but you need `t.consume()`

Comment: ok thanks it works